# How to transfer python3-flask project into yocto image?

Tags: python-3.x, linux, yocto, bitbake

I am a beginner in yocto. Till now i have learnt about how to build a yocto image and add recipes through layers.openembedded. But i am not able to figure out e.g. i have developed a python3-flask project in my PC and then i want to copy/transfer that project into my yocto os. how can i do that? do i have to make something like executable of that project and then copy that into my os using some recipe?

I have seen this recipe but i am not able to understand what does LIC_FILES_CHSUM means and where to get it? where should i put these file e.g. setup.py? in the same directory as my .bb file?
and on building where my project would be copied in the yocto os?

```
DESCRIPTION = "Simple Python setuptools hello world application"
SECTION = "examples"
LICENSE = "MIT"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://${COMMON_LICENSE_DIR}/MIT;md5=0835ade698e0bcf8506ecda2f7b4f302"

SRC_URI = "file://setup.py \
           file://python-helloworld.py \
           file://helloworld/__init__.py \
           file://helloworld/main.py"

S = "${WORKDIR}"

inherit setuptools

do_install_append () {
    install -d ${D}${bindir}
    install -m 0755 python-helloworld.py ${D}${bindir}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `LICENSE` field should obviously correspond to the license you picked for your SW. `LIC_FILES_CHKSUM` needs a file that holds the actual license defined in `LICENSE` and its md5sum passed as an "argument". It is just a way to monitor if the license ever changes. Then its md5sum changes and then the recipe fail to build because the license probably changed and requires the maintainer's attention.

`THISDIR` being the directory containing the recipe (not exactly but enough for the example), files in `SRC_URI` will be searched for in `FILESPATH` (which is first `${THISDIR}/<recipe_name>-<recipe_version>` then `${THISDIR}/<recipe-name>` then `${THISDIR}/files`). So you need to put files (the ones starting with `file://`) declared in `SRC_URI` into one of those directories.

Best would actually to have your SW in a git repo somewhere. This better follows the philosophy of having SW source code separate from your build system (what if you decide you want to use a different build system later?).

When you're wondering what some variables or tasks are doing, I highly recommend looking them up on the mega manual: https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/latest/mega-manual/mega-manual.html. This works extremely well as a "dictionary". The documentation is great albeit dense and long but it is rare not to found what you look for as a beginner.

**Update**

`LIC_FILES_CHKSUM` can be found in yocto meta/files/common-licenses in the Source Directory. You can also take your own license and check the checksum with md5sum filename and copy that to bb file. If your SW is to be distributed, it is highly recommended to have the license mentioned somewhere in your sources. So better use that part of the code in `LIC_FILES_CHKSUM` than using the ones in `${COMMON_LICENSE_DIR}` so that people will know if and when there is a license change in your project.

The below recipe works fine and you can find your app in /usr/bin directory.

```
DESCRIPTION = "Simple Python setuptools  application"
SECTION = "examples"
LICENSE = "MIT"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://${COMMON_LICENSE_DIR}/MIT;md5=0835ade698e0bcf8506ecda2f7b4f302"

SRC_URI = "file://setup.py \
        file://packagetest.py \
        file://example/__init__.py \
        file://example/file1.py \
        file://example/file2.py \
        file://example/file3.py"

S = "${WORKDIR}"

inherit pypi setuptools3

do_install_append () {
    install -d ${D}${bindir}
    install -m 0755 packagetest.py ${D}${bindir}
}
```

Comment: thanks @qschulz.. what if git repo is not public? how can i add credentials to fetch from github in the recipe? and do i also need to inherit or rdepends some python packages like flask in the recipe? or if these packages are already in the build, it is enough?. Thanks

Comment: I have updated the answer with the working recipe which i able to build by reading the yocto documentation.

Comment: If the repo is not public, adding `;protocol=ssh` in `SRC_URI` and adding SSH public keys on your git server should work. For other means, please google it or open a new question. I don't have the answer.
I don't know much about python recipes. Maybe setuptools3 class picks up the dependencies you specified in setup.py? Otherwise yes, you'd need to add them to `RDEPENDS_${PN}`.
You might not detect missing `RDEPENDS` if another package in your image `RDEPENDS` on the missing package in your recipe. It is incorrect though and should be fixed.

Comment: Finally, you `do_install_append` should be part of your installation process in one of the Python source file (setup.py probably?). This isn't specific to Yocto, so you need to make it part of your source code. Read what are the best practices for installing files from Python packages and then check if there's something to be done on Yocto side (it is often already done for you with one of the available bbclasses).